# Nativescript Http getFile got response time out error

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I used http.getFile to download video from url it returns response time out error.

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/mobilemindtec/nativescript-background-task

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I already solved it.